# Not possible to clone github repo

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I cannot find a way to clone the repo included in the following URL: https://github.com/aspnet/templating/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp

How to find the URL as to clone it? Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/templating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a repo, but a subdirectory of a repo. You can get the clone URL from the [main repository page](https://github.com/aspnet/templating).

```
git clone git@github.com:aspnet/templating.git
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/templating.git
```

Comment: Great! However, how may I find if it is a subdirectory and how may I find the address of the main repo page?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper, If you don't see a clone link, it's likely to be a subdirectory. You can find the link to the main repo right under the search bar at the top left-hand corner.